# Device Detection - to include in app webviews

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser, webview

I am creating an app for ios, android, and the web.  The application allows users to view an html page, and when they touch or click an image on that page, it does one of three things:

if it's an android device, the click calls a method in java through the javascript interface.

if it's an ios device, the click calls a method in objective c with the urlRequestShouldLoad hack.

if it's a broswer, like safari, or chrome, or anything other than an android or ios webview, it should do something different.

There will be hundreds of HTML pages that have this functionality, so I really want to avoid having to make 2 or 3 different copies of each.

So far, I've thought I would do this:

-user clicks element -> element fires inline javascript function -> function detects what agent is viewing it and determines what function to call in order to cater to device.

so the HTML page might look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
       function deviceDetection() {

        if (**device is Android application webview (not mobile broswer)**) {

            Android.myFunction();   

        } else if (**device is ios UIWebview (not mobile safari or something)**)

             window.location  = 'ios:webToNativeCall';

        } else {

            alert("you are using something other than an Android App WebView or ios UIWebview");
        }

     }
   </script>
</head>
  <body>
     <img src="..." onclick="deviceDetection()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is:

Is this the best way to handle this?  Also, if so, how do I go about detecting Android WebView or IOS UIWebview versus any other kind of broswer, mobile or not.

Thanks... help is much appreciated.